# Selecionar botões em um map

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando colocar eventos de click em uma lista que recebo de uma API. 
Esta é a resposta que retorno para o status 200. Nele eu monto os botões:

```
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      let exercicio = xhr.responseText;
      exercicio = JSON.parse(exercicio);
      let x = document.querySelector('#exercicio')
      exercicio.map(item => {
        x.innerHTML += '<a class="btn-resposta" id="btn-resposta"><div 
class="linha"><span class="icones icone-lista"></span><span>' + 
item.descricao + '</span></div></a>';
      });
    }
```

Até aqui tudo bem, o problema é que depois eu tento fazer um evento de click na class btn-resposta e só o primeiro item da lista recebe o evento de click, os demais não.
Este é o código onde faço o click:

```
function abreRespostas (){
const btnAbreRespostas = document.querySelector('.btn-resposta');
btnAbreRespostas.addEventListener('click', function(evento){
  evento.preventDefault();
  let mostra = document.querySelector('.mostra-respostas');
  mostra.classList.remove('invisivel');
    });
    }
    setTimeout(abreRespostas, 4000);
```

Tive que fazer uma function para o evento, mas foi necessário.

Resumindo, recebo uma lista da API, insiro com o innerHTML um código html na minha tela, esse código me dá uma lista com vários botões de tag . Faço um código js pra selecionar e adicionar um evento de click em cada um destes botões, porém, da forma que fiz, só está selecionando o primeiro botão que a lista exibe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que está fazendo está selecionando apenas o primeiro elemento com a classe `.btn-resposta`. Você precisa usar `querySelectorAll` para selecionar todos e fazer um laço `for` para criar um evento para cada um:

```
function abreRespostas (){
   const btnAbreRespostas = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-resposta');
   for(var x=0; x<btnAbreRespostas.length; x++){
      btnAbreRespostas[x].addEventListener('click', function(evento){
         evento.preventDefault();
         let mostra = document.querySelector('.mostra-respostas');
         mostra.classList.remove('invisivel');
      });
   }
}
setTimeout(abreRespostas, 4000);
```